# New reCAPTCHA image when going back to the HTML form to amend it

Tags: php, recaptcha

I have an HTML form saved in PHP. This form works fine. I also included a reCAPTCHA and it also works fine.

When the user fills in the form correctly he is diverted to the correct landing page. When the user submits the incorrect or missing data, he is sent to the Error page.

The error page tells the user to go BACK to the HTML form by clickink a special BACK button - which takes the user the the previous page and ammend the form. This works fine.

When the user goes from the error page to the form to amend it, he needs to resubmit it. The reCAPTCHA does not work. It seems as the 'hidden' text changes but the 'image' in the recaptcha does not change. So the user must either refresh the whole page or else the reCAPTCHA.

Is there a way how the image reCAPTCHA is refreshed automatically?

Thank you.